# Unix shell replacing a word containing backtick in a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting, backticks

I am having a sql file (`samplesqlfile`) and I want to replace a string which contains backticks with another string. Below is the code.

```
actualtext="FROM sampledatabase.\`Datatype\`"
replacetext="FROM sampledatabase.\`Datatype_details\`"
sed -i "s/\<${actualtext}\>/${replacetext}/g" samplesqlfile
```

This is not working. The actual word to be replaced is

```
FROM sampledatabase.`Datatype`
```

I added back slashes to escape the backticks. But still it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that this does not work:

```
$ sed "s/\<${actualtext}\>/${replacetext}/g" samplesqlfile
FROM sampledatabase.`Datatype`
```

But this does:

```
$ sed "s/\<${actualtext}/${replacetext}/g" samplesqlfile
FROM sampledatabase.`Datatype_details`
```

The problem was the `\>`.  The string variable `$actualtext` does not end with a word-character.  It ends with a quote.  Consequently, `\>` will never match there.  The solution is to remove `\>`.

To clarify, `\>` matches at the boundary between a word character and a non-word character where the word character appears first.  Word characters can be alphanumerics or underlines.

`\>` is a GNU extension.  The behavior under BSD/OSX sed will be different.

For purposes of illustration here, I removed the `-i` option.  For your intended use, of course, add it back.